# SpriteKit coordinates relative to the master view

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm making a Doodle-Jump like game, and I'm trying to test for if the player is below y:0 on the view. (that you access with self.view).  I have the player inside a subview, so whenever I try to get the position, it gives the relative position of the player.

Comment: If this question is solved, post an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit more googling, I was able to figure out that

```
CGPoint positionInScene = [self.scene convertPoint:self.position fromNode:self.parent];
```

fixed it!

Comment: Doesn't met me for another day. :/